# wcstombs_s is undefiend (gcc, m1 mac)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make my own programming language and compiler for it. While creating lexical analyzer i have troubles with this function. Also i included stdlib.h and stdio.h. Platform what i use is m1 mac and vscode with gcc

There is code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "Log.h"
namespace Log
{
    LOG getlog(wchar_t logfile[])
    {
        try
        {
            LOG struc;
            struc.stream = new (std::nothrow) std::ofstream;
            if (!struc.stream)
                throw ERROR_THROW(112);
            struc.stream->open(logfile);
            if (!(*(struc.stream)).is_open())
                throw ERROR_THROW(112);
            wcscpy(struc.logfile, logfile);
            return struc;
        }
        catch (Error::ERROR e)
        {
            Error::ErrorDisplay(e);
        }
    }

    void WriteLine(LOG log, char *c, ...)
    {
        for (char **c_ptr = &c; **c_ptr; c_ptr++)
        {
            *log.stream << *c_ptr;
        }
    }

    void WriteLine(LOG log, wchar_t *c, ...)
    {
        unsigned lineLength = 0;
        char *line = nullptr;
        unsigned int n = 0;

        for (wchar_t **c_ptr = &c; **c_ptr; c_ptr++)
        {
            lineLength = wcslen(*c_ptr);
            line = new char[lineLength + 1];
            wcstombs_s(&n, line, lineLength + 1u, *c_ptr, lineLength + 1u);
            *log.stream << line;
            delete[] line;
        }
    }

    void WriteLog(LOG log)
    {
        std::string line = "----Протокол------ ";
        time_t result = time(NULL);
        char str[26];
        ctime_s(str, sizeof str, &result);
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            line += str[i];
        *log.stream << line;
    }

    void WriteParm(LOG log, Parm::PARM parm)
    {
        char in_text[PARM_MAX_SIZE];
        char out_text[PARM_MAX_SIZE];
        char log_text[PARM_MAX_SIZE];
        wcstombs(in_text, parm.in, PARM_MAX_SIZE);
        wcstombs(out_text, parm.out, PARM_MAX_SIZE);
        wcstombs(log_text, parm.log, PARM_MAX_SIZE);
        *log.stream << "---- Параметры ---- \n-in: " << in_text
                                << "\n-out: " << out_text
                                << "\n-log: " << log_text;
    }

    void WriteIn(LOG log, In::IN in)
    {
        *log.stream << "\n----Исходные данные------\nКол-во символов: " << (in.size < 0 ? 0 : in.size) << std::endl
                                << "Проигнорировано: " << (in.ignor < 0 ? 0 : in.ignor) << std::endl
                                << "Кол-во строк: " << (in.lines < 0 ? 0 : in.lines) << std::endl;
    }

    void WriteError(LOG log, Error::ERROR error)
    {
        *log.stream << "Ошибка " << error.id << ": " << error.message << ", Строка " << error.inext.line << ", Позиция " << error.inext.col << std::endl;
    }

    void Close(LOG log)
    {
        (*log.stream).close();
        delete log.stream;
    }
}
```

And header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cwchar>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "In.h"
#include "Parm.h"
#include "Error.h"

namespace Log
{
    struct LOG
    {
        wchar_t logfile[PARM_MAX_SIZE];
        std::ofstream *stream;
    };

    static const LOG INITLOG{L"", NULL};
    LOG getlog(wchar_t logfile[]);
    void WriteLine(LOG log, char *c, ...);
    void WriteLine(LOG log, wchar_t *c, ...);
    void WriteLog(LOG log);
    void WriteParm(LOG log, Parm::PARM parm);
    void WriteIn(LOG log, In::IN in);
    void WriteError(LOG log, Error::ERROR error);
    void Close(LOG log);
}
```

I tried to change include path and change versions of c++, std and compilers

Comment: This is from C11, is not included into `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: @273K Never mind - OP is writing C++ code.

Comment: And are there any ways to use it?

Comment: Use `wcstombs`. You don't really need to use `wcstombs_s`, the source and the target lengths are equal.

Comment: The second, don't use C in C++. The whole code looks like you are  writing C.

Comment: This is `C` API and you tagged question `C++` is there some technical reason to use this `C` API? Why you can't just use `std::wofstream`?